# How to transform time series "row-wise" data into long format to plot multiple line charts?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**My data has the following structure:**

```
Trial        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9
1    x1 69824.35 67628.96 67976.71 68263.39 68500.94 68698.74 68864.20 69003.20 69120.43
2    x2 69824.35 67628.96 67991.52 68290.91 68538.68 68744.19 68915.02 69057.35 69176.19
3    x3 69824.35 67628.96 67973.59 68258.04 68494.10 68691.00 68856.02 68994.91 69112.27
4    x4 69824.35 67628.96 67939.18 68205.13 68433.12 68628.56 68796.14 68939.84 69063.11
5    x5 69824.35 67628.96 67983.88 68278.10 68522.57 68726.19 68896.15 69038.34 69157.55
6    x6 69824.35 67628.96 67955.75 68231.44 68464.40 68661.55 68828.66 68970.55 69091.22
```

I want to use ggplot to plot **multiple** lines.

In order to accomplish that, I know I need to get the data in **long** format. I previously used the reshape package and the melt function for that. However, my data is now in a different form. That is normally "x1" would be the colum variable (where no 1:9 is).

Now, hoever, I do have data by rows. I thus would need a transformation like:

```
Trial        1        
1    x1 69824.35 
2    x1 67628.96 
3    x1 67976.71 
4    x1 68263.39 
5    x1 68500.94 
6    x1 68698.74
```

I'm sure that this is a more trivial computation. However, I might be using the wrong keywords since I don't found anything useful via the search.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pivot_longer()` from {tidyr} to change your data into long format:

```r
# read in data
dat = structure(list(Trial = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6"), 
                     `1` = c(69824.35, 69824.35, 69824.35, 69824.35, 69824.35, 
                             69824.35), `2` = c(67628.96, 67628.96, 67628.96, 67628.96, 
                                                67628.96, 67628.96), `3` = c(67976.71, 67991.52, 67973.59, 
                                                                             67939.18, 67983.88, 67955.75), `4` = c(68263.39, 68290.91, 
                                                                                                                    68258.04, 68205.13, 68278.1, 68231.44), `5` = c(68500.94, 
                                                                                                                                                                    68538.68, 68494.1, 68433.12, 68522.57, 68464.4), `6` = c(68698.74, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             68744.19, 68691, 68628.56, 68726.19, 68661.55), `7` = c(68864.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     68915.02, 68856.02, 68796.14, 68896.15, 68828.66), `8` = c(69003.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                69057.35, 68994.91, 68939.84, 69038.34, 68970.55), `9` = c(69120.43, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           69176.19, 69112.27, 69063.11, 69157.55, 69091.22)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# pivot longer
transform_dat = dat |> 
  pivot_longer(-Trial)

# plot lines for each trial in different colour
transform_dat |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(name), y = value, colour = Trial)) +
  geom_line()
```

that creates a plot like this:

[image: Line chart]

Comment: Thank you very much. I am out this weekend but as soon as I hit my desk I am going to try this. The graph looks exactly what I replicated with an easier example in Excel. This is what I want to do in R. Great job!